# Need to fetch data based on some condition

Tags: sql

i have a table like

```
id sub_id  course date
1  2           art        01-jan-2019
1  2           sc        01-jan-2019
1  2           cmc     01-jan-2019
1  2          math     01-jan-2019
1  2           sc        02-jan-2019
1  2           cmc     02-jan-2019
1  3          math     01-jan-2019
1  3           art        01-jan-2019
2  2           sc         01-jan-2019
2  2           art        01-jan-2019
2  2           sc         01-jan-2019
```

Then i need to check for any id if distinct records are present for sub_id on the same date then priority should be given to arts then sc then cmc and last to math.
So according to the logic i should get data as:

```
id sub_id  course    date
1  2        art      01-jan-2019
1  2        sc       02-jan-2019
1  3        art      01-jan-2019
2  2        art      01-jan-2019
```

I have tried to give priority number to the data but after that i am not able to apply the logic

```
select id,sub_id,date,course,case course when art then 1
when sc then 2 when cmc then 3 else 4 end as cur_rnk from test_table;
```

So according to the logic i should get data as:

```
id sub_id  course    date
1  2        art      01-jan-2019
1  2        sc       02-jan-2019
1  3        art      01-jan-2019
2  2        art      01-jan-2019
```

Comment: Sounds good. Go ahead!

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dbms support then you can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select id,sub_id,date,course,
    row_number() over(partition by id, sub_id,date order by case course when art then 1
when sc then 2 when cmc then 3 else 4 end) as rn
from test_table
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried the solution but the result was not as expected.  records for art where picked but the record for sc was not picked.

Comment: It is showing only id sub_id  course    date
1  2        art      01-jan-2019
1  3        art      01-jan-2019
2  2        art      01-jan-2019

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It helped a lot but just for your information instead of row_number rank function worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close: try below query:

```
SELECT id
    ,sub_id
    ,DATE
    ,course
    ,CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), cur_rnk)
        WHEN '1'
            THEN 'art'
        WHEN '2'
            THEN 'sc'
        WHEN '3'
            THEN 'cmc'
        WHEN '4'
            THEN 'math'
        END AS course
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,sub_id
        ,DATE
        ,course
        ,MIN(CASE course
                WHEN art
                    THEN 1
                WHEN sc
                    THEN 2
                WHEN cmc
                    THEN 3
                ELSE 4
                END) AS cur_rnk
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY id
        ,sub_id
        ,DATE
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried it but unfortunately the result was not as expected . I am getting all the records where as my requirement is  little different.